# Include an external id when creating Zendesk support ticket via a Feedback tab

Tags: zendesk

I've been able to successfully set up a Feedback Tab for Zendesk on my site and use it to allow users to create support tickets.  My problem, however, is that I'd like to be able to track tickets by user id (which Zendesk usually calls an "external_id").

I've tried to add "external_id" to the Feedback Tab configuration, but that doesn't appear to have any effect.  Is there any way to accomplish this without coding my own feedback interface?

Answer (score 3):

External ID in Zendesk is not a settable parameter via the feedback tab.

The User ID in Zendesk is something is created when the user is created, and not related to the external ID. External ID's on user profiles are meant to be used for your own way of identifying users and can only be set via SSO or API calls. For example if you have employee numbers you can set the external ID so that agents can search by employee numbers to find the agent profiles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It looks like what I'm trying to do is possible, though not in a way that's directly supported.  Here's a link I found that has a few solutions, one of which I intended to use:  https://support.zendesk.com/entries/488390-Ability-to-pre-populate-custom-fields-in-dropbox